# ORACLE CREATE TABLE with FOREIGN KEY error

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

I am a beginner to Oracle and have been having problems creating a table with a foreign key, I have created the parent table `region` as well and have been receiving the same error. I have researched on W3school and used the same syntax but still no help.

```
CREATE TABLE region(
    region_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    region_name VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse(
    warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
    warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
    warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
    region_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES region(region_id)
);
```

Comment: Oracle syntax is different from SQL Server and MySQL; it's more like PostgreSQL.  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php'

Comment: ANSI SQL has `region_id INTEGER  REFERENCES region(region_id));`

Comment: I have understood my error now @jarlh thank you.

Comment: I don't see any error in the first CREATE TABLE (for REGION), and on my system it created a table without any problems. The second statement has an error in the last line: remove the words FOREIGN KEY, which are not part of the syntax (even though I see why you may believe that). Other than that, the second statement works fine on my system too. It is not mandatory to give the data type of REGION_ID in the second table; it will be - by default - the same data type as the PK from the REGION table, which it references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave "`FOREIGN KEY`" out, if you want to declare a foreign key constraint inline.

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse(
warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
region_id REFERENCES region(region_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare column `region_id`, and then put a foreign key constraint on it:

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse(
    warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
    warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
    warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
    region_id INTEGER,
    constraint warehouse_region_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES region(region_id)
);
```

Or you can use the short-circuit syntax, aka the inline constraint syntax (in which case Oracle will assign a default name to the constraint):

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse(
    warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
    warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
    warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
    region_id integer REFERENCES region(region_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several posiblities.

Master table first:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE region(
  2  region_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3  region_name VARCHAR2(20)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Inline constraint (at the same line as the column):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE warehouse(
  2  warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3  warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
  4  warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
  5  warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
  6  region_id INTEGER constraint fk_wr REFERENCES region(region_id));

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Outline constraint (at the end of the `create table`):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE warehouse(
  2  warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3  warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
  4  warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
  5  warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
  6  region_id INTEGER,
  7  --
  8  constraint fk_wr foreign key (region_id) references region (region_id));

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Using `alter table`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE warehouse(
  2  warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3  warehouse_address VARCHAR2(20),
  4  warehouse_postcode VARCHAR2(8),
  5  warehouse_phonenm INTEGER,
  6  region_id INTEGER);

Table created.

SQL> alter table warehouse add constraint fk_wr foreign key (region_id)
  2  references region (region_id);

Table altered.

SQL>
```